# Git how to insert a different common ancestor for merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I am trying to merge two different branches in Git like this:

```
                         [Mod 1 binary] - [Mod 1 Text]
                    /                                 \
[Original(Binary)]                                      [CombinedText]   
                    \                                 /
                         [Mod 2 Binary] - [Mod 2 Text]
```

The problem is that the merge tool I am using can only handle text files so the binary file does not work as a common ancestor. I want to make a text file from the original binary file with a conversion tool ant then have a structure like this so I can merge:

```
                                     [Mod 1 Text]
                                   /               \
[OriginalBinary] - [Original Text]                    [Combined Text]
                                   \                /
                                     [Mod 2 Text]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: In your top diagram there is no `Original Text`, so how does it magically get inserted in the bottom diagram?

Comment: I would checkout the `[Original Binary]` commit, run it through a conversion tool, and then commit on a new branch. I will edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
$git replace --graft hash([Mod 1 Text]) hash([Original text])
$git replace --graft hash([Mod 2 Text]) hash([Original text])
```

git will merge both `[Mod 1 Text]` `[Mod 2 Text]` as if `[Original text]` is their common parent. You can later remove the replacement with `git replace -d hash([Mod 1 Text]) hash([Mod 2 Text])` if you feel like.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace for details.

Comment: Ended up manually merging but this is the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should do exactly what you said: "commit on a new branch".  In a shell-based session your task might go like this:

```
$ git checkout -b work-br <commit-id>
```

(here `<commit-id>` is the ID of the commit containing `OriginalBinary`), then:

```
$ tool_cmd [options] binary [> text]  # or however this works
$ git add text
$ git commit
```

You now have:

```
    B - C        <-- branch-1
  /
A
 \\
 |  D - E        <-- branch-2
 |
 |
  \
    F            <-- work-br
```

where commit `A` has only the original binary, `B` has `Mod1 Binary`, `C` has `Mod1 Text`, `D` has `Mod2 Binary`, and `E` has `Mod2 Text`.  New commit `F` has both the original binary and the text-ified version.

At this point you can make two (or just one, really) more branch and then `git cherry-pick` commit `C` into one of the two new branches, switch to the other branch, `git chery-pick` commit `E` into the other, and have this graph fragment:

```
    B - C        <-- branch-1
  /
A
 \\
 |  D - E        <-- branch-2
 |
 |      C'       <-- work-branch-1
  \   /
    F
      \
        E'       <-- work-branch-2
```

Now you can merge the text files (ignoring or even removing the binary files if need be) to get a merged result, which you can then import back to whichever original branch you want, or even just use directly from this new set of branches.

Comment: I had tried something similar to this approach. The problem is that when I try to pick `C` to `C'`, for example, this fails because the common ancestor is `A` which is a binary file. That's why I was trying to make a common ancestor other than A and C' because A is a binary file.

Comment: As I said, *ignoring **or even removing** the binary files if need be*: the nice thing about doing this on a second set of side branches is that you can discard anything that's getting in the way.  Resolve the conflict between binaries however you like, since you won't be using them.  (In fact you might want to simply remove the binary files entirely from every commit in the path, i.e., from `F`, `C'`, and `E'`: note that `cherry-pick -n` gives you a chance to modify the commit before committing the cherry-pick result.)

Comment: I guess I didn't explain well enough: the binary files were converted to text files but the common base is binary. I still need to merge the text files taht originated from the common binary file

Comment: The common base for your new merge (in the diagram above) is `F`, which—if you remove the binaries—has no binaries, only text.  Likewise, `C'` and `E'` contain text (and if you remove the binaries, *only* text).  Incidentally, note that when you get a merged result, the point of that merged result is simply to allow you to copy it back to the original goal-merge, of `C` and `E` on the original branches.  (Remember, git doesn't care how you got a merged result once you `git add` and `git commit`.)